# Using QApplication with command line arguments

Tags: qt, qt4

```
QApplication::QApplication ( int & argc, char ** argv )
```

> Initializes the window system and **constructs an application object
>   with argc command line arguments in argv.**
>
> Warning: The data referred to by argc and argv must stay valid for the
>   entire lifetime of the QApplication object. **In addition, argc must be
>   greater than zero and argv must contain at least one valid character
>   string.**

From this link: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qapplication.html#QApplication

What can be the arguments to the executable file? Any examples?

I tried specifying something like:

```
anisha@linux-dopx:~/Desktop/notes/qt> make
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I../../../qtsdk-2010.05/qt/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I../../../qtsdk-2010.05/qt/include/QtCore -I../../../qtsdk-2010.05/qt/include/QtGui -I../../../qtsdk-2010.05/qt/include -I. -I. -o widgets.o widgets.cpp
g++ -m64 -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-rpath,/home/anisha/qtsdk-2010.05/qt/lib -o qt widgets.o    -L/home/anisha/qtsdk-2010.05/qt/lib -lQtGui -L/home/anisha/qtsdk-2010.05/qt/lib -L/usr/X11R6/lib64 -lQtCore -lpthread 

anisha@linux-dopx:~/Desktop/notes/qt> ./qt 2 f g
anisha@linux-dopx:~/Desktop/notes/qt>
```

Nothing *special* happened, nor I knew what I was doing or what I was supposed to do.

**EDIT 1:** The code on which I tried the `./qt -style=windows`.

```
#include <QtGui>

 int main (int argc, char *argv[])
 {
    QApplication app (argc, argv);

    QWidget objQWidget;
    objQWidget.show                 ();     
    objQWidget.resize               (320, 240);     
    objQWidget.setWindowTitle ("Text to be shown on the title bar\n");

    // Adding a "child" widget.
    QPushButton *objQPushButton = new QPushButton ("Text to be shown on the button", &objQWidget);
    objQPushButton->move         (100, 100);
    objQPushButton->show         ();

    return app.exec                   ();
 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Continue reading that documentation. The set of flags `QApplication` acts on is listed there.

Try for example:

```
./qt -style=windows
```

The arguments that `QApplication` doesn't deal with are simply left alone. The ones it does process are removed (which is why that function takes non-const arguments).

Comment: Oh, yeah, thanks, I did read it further now, saw a lot of flags, tried your example too, but it didn't do anything special to the output. Well anyway, that's another problem.

Comment: I must make a point by now, to at least read the full page before asking the question here.

Comment: It won't do anything if you don't display a GUI... And since you didn't post the code you used above, I have no idea if you're passing  `main`'s arguments to `QApplication`'s constructor.

Comment: Well try the other styles. Your code is fine (except that aligning the arguments like that is really uncommon and, to me, really distracting). Print out `argc` before and after having initialized QApplication to see that that constructor is "eating" some of the arguments.

Answer (score 6):

The arguments passed in the constructor are later accessible through the static method
`QStringList QCoreApplication::arguments()`. By this, command line arguments can be handled everywhere in your code.

Answer (score 4):

The suggestion about using QCoreApplication is only recommended of you have a console application. If you are using a QApplication instead, and want to access command-line arguments from inside a QWidget, you can do it with the global pointer qApp:

[Here](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_use_QApplication_in_Qt) you can find the documentation from Nokia, or [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qapplication.html#qApp) from qt-project.org . In the documentation browser of Qt Creator I couldn't find it, so it is at best not that easily accessible.

so you can find:

int my_argc = qApp->arguments().count();

QString my_argv_0 = qApp->arguments.at(0);

...

and so on.

I know this question is old, but took me some time to find a way to do it from within my Main Window, so hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, Dissident penguin! This helped me a lot!
Just note that:

```
QString my_argv_0 = qApp->arguments.at(0);
```

should be replaced with:

```
QString my_argv_0 = qApp->arguments().at(0);
```

(note the additional () after 'arguments')